# Interop - how to insert cmake options

Tags: nanoframework

I tried following tutorial to use c++ assemblies in nanoframework:
[Interop in Net Framework](https://jsimoesblog.wordpress.com/2018/06/19/interop-in-net-nanoframework/)

I don't get any further with the cmake options!?
Where do I find or how do I insert the cmake-variants.json file for ESP32 and where to place it?
I have installed cmake options for Visual Studio.

I also can not find the file in the nanoframework sample:
[Interop Sample](https://github.com/nanoframework/Samples/tree/main/samples/Interop)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it to a local clone of the [nf-interpreter](https://github.com/nanoframework/nf-interpreter) repository, which you'll use to build an image. Instructions for building for ESP32 can be found [here](https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/building/build-esp32.html).